# File upload using ajax and jQuery in Spring without using FormData

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

I want to upload an excel file in my application using ajax,jQuery and Spring form. Following is my code. I am able to hit the controller with @modelAttribute which is nothing but a Simple Java Class having one Multipart file attribute but that file attribute in the FileUploadForm is null when the request is coming to Controller. Can anyone suggest what wrong I am doing. I am doing this in IE8 so can not use FormData. Thanks in advance.

**JSP**

```
<script
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var form = $('#myForm');
    form.find('#submitButton').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : form.attr('action'),
            enctype : 'multipart/form-data',
            data : form.attr('modelAttribute'),
            success : function(data) {
                alert("Success"+data);
            },
            error : function(data) {
                alert("error");
            }
        }); 
    });
});

   </script>
 </head>
<body>
<form:form method="post" action="upload" id="myForm"
    modelAttribute="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <table id="fileTable">
        <tr>
            <td><input name="file" id="uploadedFile" type="file"  /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
<!-- <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Upload">
                                           Upload</button> -->
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitButton" 
                                           value="Upload" />
</form:form>
```

And following is my controller code.

**Controller**

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleFileUpload(@ModelAttribute("uploadForm") FileUploadForm form,
              Model model) {
    MultipartFile file = form.getFile();
    String name = file.getOriginalFilename();
    FileSystemResource fsr = new FileSystemResource(name);
    StatusVO statusVO = service.loadAndProcessUploadedFile(fsr.getFile());
    model.addAttribute("status", statusVO);
    return "/common/message";
}
```

Following is FileUplaodForm Class
**FileUploadForm.java**

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

public class FileUploadForm {

    private MultipartFile file;

    public MultipartFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(MultipartFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

Comment: You had a submit button in your form then why do need to send it via ajax. I hope simply remove the ajax will make your page work. All you need to do is return back to the same page.

Comment: Hi Vinoth, the thing is form is not getting submitted by submit button thats why I have to submit it manually.

Comment: So that becomes real issue. Just remove the ajax part and check the browser console whether did u get any error on submit. I hope your issue is `you are using spring form and not the spring controls.` Change everything into same type either spring or normal form.

Comment: Try to send the `$('#myForm').serialize()` as a data to the controller and check.

Answer (score 0):

If form is not getting submitted by submit button, simply try like this,

```
var form = $('#myForm');
form.find('#submitButton').click(function() {
    form.submit();      //This will submit your form.
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your quick response but i got it solved. Ajax not at all works with file uploads. So I removed all ajax related code and made it simple form submit. Now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Thanks all for your quick response but i got it solved. Ajax not at all works with file uploads. So I removed all ajax related code and made it simple form submit. Now working fine.

Comment: add what you modified to your answer and mark as answer.